# Decode JSON into Elm Maybe

Tags: json, decode, elm

Given the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Item 1",
    "desc": "The first item"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Item 2"
  }
]
```

How do you decode that into the following Model:

```
type alias Model =
    { id : Int
    , name : String
    , desc : Maybe String
    }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Brian Hicks has a series of posts on JSON decoders, you probably want to specifically look at `Adding New Fields to Your JSON Decoder` (which handles the scenario where you may or may not receive a field from a JSON object).

To start with, you'll probably want to use the [elm-decode-pipeline package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline).  You can then use the [`optional` function](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/latest/Json-Decode-Pipeline#optional) to declare that your `desc` field may not be there.  As Brian points out in the article, you can use the [`maybe`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#maybe) decoder from [the core `Json.Decode` package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode), but it will produce `Nothing` for *any* failure, not just being `null`.  There *is* a [`nullable`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#nullable) decoder, which you could also consider using, if you don't want to use the pipeline module.

Your decoder could look something like this:

```
modelDecoder : Decoder Model
modelDecoder =
    decode Model
        |> required "id" int
        |> required "name" string
        |> optional "desc" (Json.map Just string) Nothing
```

[Here's a live example on Ellie.](https://embed.ellie-app.com/qxW4MW58dQa1/1)

Comment: After posting my question, further Googling led me to Brian Hicks' post on JSON decoders. I was pleased to see your answer when I came back. Glad to have found a good source, that's helpful to others as well.

Comment: In your last line, I think you want `(Json.map Just string)` as opposed to `Json.map Just int)`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it with `string` and an Ellie example.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes! I came to same answer based on Brian Hicks' info. I'm marking your answer as accepted, since you posted first.

Comment: As of Elm 0.19 the package has been renamed to to [elm-json-decode-pipeline](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline)

Answer (score 18):

So if you're looking for a zero-dependency solution that doesn't require `Json.Decode.Pipeline`.

```
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)


modelDecoder : Decoder Model
modelDecoder =
    Decode.map3 Model
        (Decode.field "id" Decode.int)
        (Decode.field "name" Decode.string)
        (Decode.maybe (Decode.field "desc" Decode.string))
```

If you want to do this using the `Model` constructor as an applicative functor (because you'd need more 8 items).

```
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)
import Json.Decode.Extra as Decode


modelDecoder : Decoder Model
modelDecoder =
    Decode.succeed Model
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "id" Decode.int)
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "name" Decode.string)
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.maybe (Decode.field "desc" Decode.string))
```

Both of which can be used with `List`s with `Decode.list modelDecoder`. I wish the applicative functions were in the standard library, but you'll have to reach into all of the *-extra libraries to get these features. Knowing how applicative functors work will help you understand more down the line, so I'd suggest reading about them. The Decode Pipeline solution abstracts this simple concept, but when you run into the need for `Result.andMap` or any other of the `andMap`s because there's not a `mapN` for your module or a DSL, you'll know how to get to your solution.

Because of the applicative nature of decoders, all fields should be able to be processed asynchronously and in parallel with a small performance gain, instead of synchronously like `andThen`, and this applies to every place that you use `andMap` over `andThen`. That said, when debugging switching to `andThen` can give you a place to give yourself an usable error per field that can be changed to `andMap` when you know everything works again.

Under the hood, `JSON.Decode.Pipeline` uses `Json.Decode.map2` (which is `andMap`), so there's no performance difference, but uses a DSL that's negligibly more "friendly".

Comment: This should probably be the chosen response. Theres no need to pull in a completely separate dependency just because you have this behavior in your API. Its supported out of the box.

Comment: On advantage of the `andThen` route is that you have the opportunity to bind out the a specific error message, but that's mostly useful when debugging. `andMap` should technically be parallelizable because it's applicative.

Answer (score 2):

Brian Hicks' ["Adding New Fields to Your JSON Decoder"](https://www.brianthicks.com/post/2016/12/29/adding-new-fields-to-your-json-decoder/) post helped me develop the following. For a working example, see [Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/qx86WH3fD5a1/3)

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)
import Json.Decode.Pipeline as JP
import String

type alias Item =
    { id : Int
    , name : String
    , desc : Maybe String
    }


main =
    Decode.decodeString (Decode.list itemDecoder) payload
        |> toString
        |> String.append "JSON "
        |> text


itemDecoder : Decoder Item
itemDecoder =
    JP.decode Item
        |> JP.required "id" Decode.int
        |> JP.required "name" Decode.string
        |> JP.optional "desc" (Decode.map Just Decode.string) Nothing
```